# Como pegar a cor principal de uma ImageView?

Tags: android, imagem

Queria saber sem ter que postar meu código, como pegar a cor principal de um certo ponto dentro de uma `ImageView`, por exemplo tenho um quadro e dentro desse quadro tem 3 cores,
a cor na direita é vermelho, a cor na esquerda é azul, e a cor do meio é preta, mas eu só quero pegar a cor do meio sem ter que retornar que a cor da esquerda ou da direita é azul/vermelho.
Como eu faço isso ?
Se alguém poder me ajudar ficaria muito agradecido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para obter a cor de um determinado pixel de uma ***ImageView*** utilize o método ***getPixel*** do ***Bitmap*** associado à ***ImageView***.

Código para obter a cor do pixel do centro:

```
Bitmap bitmap=((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
//Coordenada x do centro
int x = bitmap.getWidth()/2;
//Coordenada y do centro
int y = bitmap.getHeight()()/2;

int cor = bitmap.getPixel(x,y);
```

Tenha atenção que as coordenadas(x,y) têm de ser referentes ao ***Bitmap*** e não à ***ImageView***.
Para obter a cor de um qualquer pixel, se as coordenadas(x,y) se referem à ***ImageView***, elas terão de ser convertidas:

```
double bitmapWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
double bitmapHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
double imageViewWidth = imageView.getWidth();
double imageViewHeight = imageView.getHeigth();

int bitmapX = (int)(x * (bitmapWidth / imageViewWidht));
int bitmapY = (int)(y * (bitmapHeight / imageViewHeight));
int cor = bitmap.getPixel(bitmapX,bitmapY);
```

Comment: Fala cara, beleza ?
Então muito obrigado aí por me responder,
você poderia me ajudar em mais uma coisa ?
Eu queria saber se depois que eu pegar essa cor eu poderia utilizar um if para verificar que cor que ele achou no centro, em hexadecimal mas se você tiver outra solução sem ser em hexadecimal, eu agradeço valeu!

Comment: Esse hexadecimal está guardado numa string?

Comment: `Color.parseColor(string)` retorna um `int`. Veja [aqui](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#parseColor%28java.lang.String%29) o formato da *string*.

Comment: Sim, até ai tudo bem mais eu poderia fazer assim:
`if(colorfoto == white){
   //condição
}`

Comment: Qual valor eu teria de usar no lugar de white, para definir se a cor no centro da foto é branca ou não ?

Comment: `if(colorfoto == Color.WHITE){.....}`

Comment: E se fosse outro tipo de cor tipo snow.

Comment: Se você souber o Hexadecimal faça assim: `if(colorfoto == Color.parseColor("#FFFAFA")){...}`

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18985/discussion-between-gutie-and-ramaral).